# How to use node.js var in pugs java script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am passing a variable from my server-side (node)file to my client-side pug file-

```
const prods_arr = [
   {Types: "Electronic",Brand: "Apple", Products: [ "MacBook Pro", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini"]}, 
   {Types: "Electronic", Brand: "Dell", Products: [ "Inspioren", "Latitude"]},
   {Types: "Electronic", Brand: "Samsung", Products: [ "Galaxy S20", "Galaxy S10"]}
];

res.render("./products", {
     pageTitle: "products",
     prods: prods_arr
});
```

I am displaying the content of `prods` array in the pug file -

```
select(name="type" onchange="change()")#type
    option(value="Null") "Type"
    for (products in prods) {
        option(value=products.Type) #{procucts.Type}
    }

select(name="brands")#brands
     option(value="Null") "Brand"
```

Now I want to use the `prods` array inside the script tag.

```
script.
    function change() {
        var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var brand = document.getElementById("brands");
        
        for (brands in prods) {
            if (brands.Type == type) {
                const brandOption = new Option(brands.Brand, brands.Brand);
                brand.add(brandOption, undefined);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I use my `prods` array in the script tag??

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How are you using the variable in the scripts tag?

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna edit my question and add an example.

Comment: Did you try stackoverflow.com/a/69633769/936293? The data is passed in `const data = JSON.parse("!{JSON.stringify(data)}");` if your data does not contain `"`. Otherwise use the backtick ` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your trying to say here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stringify your array

```
script.
  function change() {
    const type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    const brand = document.getElementById("brands");
    
    for (const prod of !{JSON.stringify(prods)}) {
      if (prod.Types === type) {
        const brandOption = new Option(prod.Brand, prod.Brand);
        brand.add(brandOption, undefined);
      }
    }
  }
```

`!{JSON.stringify(prods)}` returns a verbatim JSON string of the array and you can use JSON as object/array literals in JavaScript.

The output is

```
<script>function change() {
  const type = document.getElementById("type").value;
  const brand = document.getelementById("brands");
  
  for (prod in [{"Types":"Electronic","Brand":"Apple","Products":["MacBook Pro","MacBook Air","Mac Mini"]},{"Types":"Electronic","Brand":"Dell","Products":["Inspioren","Latitude"]},{"Types":"Electronic","Brand":"Samsung","Products":["Galaxy S20","Galaxy S10"]}]) {
    if (prod.Types === type) {
      const brandOption = new Option(prod.Brand, prod.Brand);
      brand.add(brandOption, undefined);
    }
  }
}</script>
```

You have multiple other errors in your code. This is the working code

```
select(name="type" onchange="change()")#type
    option(value="Null") Type
    each prod in prods 
      option(value=prod.Types) #{prod.Types}

select(name="brands")#brands
     option(value="Null") Brand

script.
  function change() {
    const type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    const brand = document.getElementById("brands");
    
    for (const prod of !{JSON.stringify(prods)}) {
      if (prod.Types === type) {
        const brandOption = new Option(prod.Brand, prod.Brand);
        brand.add(brandOption, undefined);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Still the same output. I am getting empty option boxes.

Comment: @Avi Your whole code in the question is broken. You have multiple typos and syntax errors, e.g. `Type` instead of `Types` and missing closing parenthesis. The `for` loop is wrong in Pug. `getelementById` should be `getElementById`. You're using `for...in` instead of `for...of`.

Comment: As I mentioned it is an example of my code and I rewrote it, so it has a few typos.

Comment: Thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: `for of` worked thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it like that. `prods` is a server-side variable, you have to tweak it in order to access it from client-side. The best suggestion would be not to do that. However, the tweak would be to render it as JSON string in the HTML before you send it to the client, and then read that in the client-side JS.

Example:

```html
<meta name="prods" content="{{ JSON.stringify(prods) }}">
```

```js
const prods = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('meta[name="prods"]').content);
console.log(prods);
```

Comment: So, I need to add `meta(name="prods" content="{{ JSON.stringify(prods) }}")` in my pug code. But where do I add `const prods = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('meta[name="prods"]').content);
console.log(prods);`

Comment: Inside `script` element.

Comment: Didn't work, I used the const name(prods) to loop but didn't work

Comment: Show full code.

Comment: `script.
    function change() {
        var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var brand = document.getelementById("brands);
        const prods = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('meta[name="prods"]').content); console.log(prods);
        for (brands in prods) {
            if (brands.Type == type) {
                const brandOption = new Option(brands.Brand, brands.Brand);
                brand.add(brandOption, undefined);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: And what's that supposed to produce?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238482/discussion-between-avi-and-msrumon).

Comment: It is supposed to add options to the brands selection field with the values of prods.Brand